How to connect two different versions of mysql db in oracle sql developer
I have 2 different versions of mysql db with version "8.0.37 commercial" & "5.7.9 enterprise commercial".
I am trying to connect through oracle sql developer and in third party jdbc drivers using mysql-connector-j-8.0.1 DB with version 5.7.9 is not able to connect and when I am using jdbc driver com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5 DB with version 8.0.37 is connecting.
Error message  when connecting 5.7.9 version with mysql-connector-j-8.0.1
Error message when connection 8.0.37 version with com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5
Is there any way I can connect both servers at same time with some compatible driver or workaround.

5.7 is past end of life and no longer receiving security updates.  but if you were still  on 5.7.9, almost 10 years old, you weren't applying security updates anyway.  consider it highly insecure and upgrade as soon as you can.

5.7.9 is a legacy system and soon it will be removed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
